# two verbs, past participle used as attribute

Tags: grammar

Can I say, for instance, "[some people] conducted research **supervised** and **guided** by the committee"
Is it grammatical that there are two verbs?

Answer (score 2):

You can use as many verbs as you like, although too many will look awkward. Some people conducted research sponsored, designed, supervised, monitored, guided and appraised by the committee. Police said a man was 'lucky to be alive' after being slapped, punched, kicked, stabbed, shot, and burned by a gang of thugs.